# One-statement Insert+delete in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a PostgreSQL table `t` that looks like

```
 id | name | y
----+------+---
 0  | 'a'  | 0
 1  | 'b'  | 0
 2  | 'c'  | 0
 3  | 'd'  | 1
 4  | 'e'  | 2
 5  | 'f'  | 2
```

With id being the primary key and with a UNIQUE constraint on `(name, y)`.

Suppose I want to update this table in such a way that the part of the data set with `y = 0` becomes (without knowing what is already there)

```
 id | name | y
----+------+---
 0  | 'a'  | 0
 1  | 'x'  | 0
 2  | 'y'  | 0
```

I could use

```
DELETE FROM t WHERE y = 0 AND name NOT IN ('a', 'x', 'y');
INSERT INTO t (name, y) VALUES ('a', 0), ('x', 0), ('y', 0)
    ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING;
```

I feel like there must be a one-statement way to do this (like what upsert does for the task "update the existing entries and insert missing ones", but then for "insert the missing entries and delete the entries that should not be there"). Is there? I heard rumours that oracle has something called `MERGE`... I'm not sure what it does exactly.

Comment: What's wrong with running two statements?

Comment: Well... If there exists one clear-cut statement that does the same, two statements is overkill and extra complexity.

Comment: The work that that single statement would have to do, would exactly be the same as the work those two statements do.

Comment: As in [upsert](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/)?

Comment: The text of your question says "update the existing entries and insert missing ones" which is not what your two statements are doing.  At a minimum, your conflict target should be (name, y).

Comment: The work that the single statement has to do may be the same (although I doubt that), but the amount of work required from the programmer is less. Since the complexity of a program (the amount of work required to understand it) is increased by the SQL queries it employs, having one statement instead of two would reduce the complexity.

Comment: I meant that "update the existing entries and insert missing ones" is what upsert is for, to illustrate a case of a "statement that does two things at the same time".

Comment: @TempestasLudi If you have two simple operations, use two simple statements in a transaction. Trying to smash them together into one is *more* complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *can* be done with a single statement. But I doubt whether that classifies as "simpler".

Additionally: your expected output doesn't make sense.

Your insert statement does not provide a value for the primary key column (`id`), so apparently, the `id` column is a generated (identity/serial) column.

But in that case, news rows can't have the same IDs as the ones before because when the new rows were inserted, new IDs were generated.

Given the above change to your expected output, the following does what you want:

```
with data (name, y) as (
  values ('a', 0), ('x', 0), ('y', 0)
), changed as (
  insert into t (name, y) 
  select *
  from data
  on conflict (name,y) do nothing
)
delete from t
where (name, y) not in (select name, y from data);
```

That is one statement, but certainly not "simpler". The only advantage I can see is that you do not have to specify the list of values twice.

Online example: https://rextester.com/KKB30299

Comment: Thank you. However, if that is the best solution, I won't bother and just do it with two separate statements. :P

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, do you know if there is a performance benefit from a single statement? I think it is one snapshot per statement, so I would assume fewer snapshots is better perf wise.

Answer (score -3):

Unless there's a tremendous number of rows to be updated, do it as three update statements.

```
update t set name = 'a' where id = 0;
update t set name = 'x' where id = 1;
update t set name = 'y' where id = 2;
```

This is simple. It's easily done in a loop with a SQL builder. There's no race conditions as there are with deleting and inserting. And it preserves the ids and other columns of those rows.

To demonstrate with some psuedo-Ruby code.

```
new_names = ['a', 'x', 'y']

# In a transaction
db.transaction {
  # Query the matching IDs in the same order as their new names
  ids_to_update = db.select("
    select id from t where y = 0 order by id
  ")

  # Iterate through the IDs and new names together
  ids_to_update.zip(new_names).each { |id,name|
    # Update the row with its new name
    db.execute("
      update t set name = ? where id = ?
    ", name, id)
  }
}
```

---

Fooling around some, here's how I did it in "one" statement, or at least one thing sent to the server, while preserving the IDs and no race conditions.

```
do $$
    declare change text[];
    declare changes text[][];
begin
    select array_agg(array[id::text,name])
      into changes
      from unnest(
         (select array_agg(id order by id) from t where y = 0),
         array['a','y','z']
      ) with ordinality as a(id, name);

    foreach change slice 1 in array changes
    loop
        update t set name = change[2] where id = change[1]::int;
    end loop;
end$$;
```

The goal is to produce an array of arrays matching the id to its new name. That can be iterated over to do the updates.

```
      unnest(
         (select array_agg(id order by id) from t where y = 0),
         array['a','y','z']
      ) with ordinality as a(id, name);
```

That bit produces rows with the IDs and their new names side by side.

```
    select array_agg(array[id::text,name])
      into changes
      from unnest(...) with ordinality as a(id, name);
```

Then those rows of IDs and names are turned into an array of arrays like: `{{1,a},{2,y},{3,z}}`. (There's probably a more direct way to do that)

```
    foreach change slice 1 in array changes
    loop
        update t set name = change[2] where id = change[1]::int;
    end loop;
```

Finally we loop over the array and use it to perform each update.

You can turn this into a proper function and pass in the y value to match and the array of names to change them to. You should verify that the length of the ids and names match.

This might be faster, depends on how many rows you're updating, but it isn't simpler, and it took some time to puzzle out.

Comment: This only works if you know exactly what the contents of the table (with `y=0`) are. I asked for a solution that requires no prior knowledge of the table.

Comment: @TempestasLudi You can select the IDs and loop over them in a transaction using a programming language. That's what the second part of the answer does in "one" statement. It's not really to use, more to demonstrate how complex smashing everything into one statement gets.

Comment: @TempestasLudi I think I'm confused by your use of "update". Do you want to update existing rows? Or blow away all rows where `y=0` and insert a possibly different number of new rows? If it's the latter, there's no `upsert` equivalent. An `upsert` works on a single set of provided values, it's just what to do when there's an insert conflict. You want to insert from a set, and delete everything which matches a query (`y=0`) but *does not* match the set. Those are two different sets, so two statements.